# Sign out/Restart/Power off background color stuck on Blue. Blue flash on lock-screen

Tags: windows-10, themes, color-theme

I have installed a third party black theme for my system: Gray Dark by KDr3w on DeviantArt:
https://www.deviantart.com/kdr3w/art/Gray-Dark-807271550

Problem:
Everything was perfect until recent system update. Now, each time I signing out, restarting, or powering off, background color of a window with circling dots is stuck on Blue color, while it was following 3rd party theme color before - Gray. Also each time I lock screen, there is a blue flash transition.

What I have tried:

- Revert back to original theme and unmodified dll files by uninstalling UltraUXThemePatcher.
- Tried to change accent, but the issue got even worse: Red-Blue flash transition on lock-screen + Singing out/Restarting/Powering off screen's background color is still blue.

Could anyone point me in the right direction what should I change in order to make that window background color to follow 3rd party theme again?

Examples:

[Stuck Blue color on Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgCpo.jpg)

Red-Blue Flash on lock-screen (When Red accent applied)

https://youtu.be/tU47GFvFF1o

Blue Flash on lock-screen (When Gray accent applied)

https://youtu.be/xxx2kyod8Kw

UPD: So I am basically at my wit's end. I have tried everything and asked everywhere. Everything is Gray, but Sing-out/Restart/Power-off screen color remains to be blue, ARGGGGGHHHH:

[image: APT Settings]

[image: DWM]
[image: Accent Settings]

Comment: so strange about your issue. Did you checked those symptoms in safe mode environment? If not, try to check to narrow down your issue. By the way, I noticed you said issue occur after update system, which update you installed? Did you try to uninstall it?

Comment: I have just updated to 20H2 from 2004 (19041.685) , but issue still persists. I will try with Safe mode.

Comment: Yep, issue persists in Safe mode.

Comment: If issue occur after upgrade to 20H2, you could roll back to 2004 in 10 days. As it persists in Safe Mode, you could uninstall existing graphic driver, download latest graphic driver from device manufacturer website to check.

Comment: Have rolled back to 2004, issue persists and I am on the latest video driver, since it is X220 Lenovo, pertty old laptop, so the video driver is as latest as it can get :D :D ;D

Comment: how about back up your system and reset it or clean install ?

Comment: I have too many valuable apps installed on my laptop, do not want to go through installing them again and setting up the system from scratch just because of this issue :D, hope there is another way